# Expected value of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, bernoulli-numbers

Consider a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli trials with $P(\text{success})=p$. Let $X_i$ and $X_j$ be indicator variables of the number of "success" in $i$th and $j$th runs. Given the total number of success was $m$, $m<n$. I am asked to compute the correlation coefficient for $X_i$ and $X_j$.

Now I know the formula for correlation coefficient, but to compute the co-variance I will need to find $E(X_i)$ and $E(X_j)$ first. By definition does $E(X_i)=p_i$ and $E(X_j)=p_j$? I feel this seems a bit too easy but I can't see whats wrong with it.

Comment: The question is not clear.  The phrase "Given the total number of success was m, m" is disconnected. The phrase "let Xi and Xj be indicator variables of the number of "success" in ith and jth runs" is unclear . A "run"  is usually a sequence of successes/failures. Do you mean that $X_i$ takes values 0/1 according to the value of the i-th trial? Or does it count the number of successes up to time "i"?

Comment: I re-read the problem and I believe that I made a mistake in the title. Xi and Xj are in fact Binomial random variables. So this answered my own question since E(Xi)=ip for Binomial. Also for clarification Xi counts the number of successes up to time i.

Comment: Hmmm... in all probability, the answer below squarely misses the question asked, but, to be fair, the OP themselves misled everybody with their comment. My bet would go on the following exercise: *Consider $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $(X_i)$ with $P(X_i=1)=p$, $P(X_i=0)=1-p$, and $S=X_1+\cdots+X_n$.Compute the correlation of $X_i$ and $X_j$ for $i\ne j$, conditionally on $S=m$, for each $m$ between $0$ and $n$.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. For a discrete random variable $X$ the expected value is equal to 
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbf{Z}} k \Pr(X=k),
$$
which is simply $\Pr(X=1):= p$ for the Bernoulli case.

Comment: Should a discrete random variable take only integer values?

Comment: That is not necessary, it was just how I chose to write it. In general, a discrete random variable will take values in some countable or finite space $\Omega \subset \mathbf{R}$, and then you would write
$$
\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \omega \Pr(X=\omega)
$$

Comment: However, the second phrase in your answer is incorrect. 
There exists a lot of discrete random variables $X$ such that their expected values does not equal to $$\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb Z} k \text{Pr}(X=k)$$. For example, if $Pr(X=3.5)=1$, then $EX=3.5$  but 
$$\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb Z} k \text{Pr}(X=k) =0.$$

Comment: In that case 3.5 would be an element of $\Omega$.

Comment: Let it be, it does not matter. This will not make correct the second phrase in your answer to the original question.